# Negative number modulo 2

Tags: javascript, math

Admittedly my maths is not that strong. Why do these two examples give differing results?

**Example One**

```
function isOdd(num) {
  return (num % 2) == 1 ? true : false;
}
console.log(isOdd(-17));
```

Output: `false` (incorrect)

**Example Two**

```
function isOdd(num) {
  return (num % 2) != 0 ? true : false;
}
console.log(isOdd(-17));
```

Output: `true` (correct)

**Console Test**

```
console.log(-17 % 2);
```

The output was ***-1***, rather than *1*.

Any odd number mod 2 always equals 1, does it not? So why is this happening? Why do I need to test for `!= 0` in order to get the right answer? Why does `== 1` yield a wrong answer?

Comment: a negative number modulo a number is always negative ... even when it's `-0` - by the way ... `return (num % 2) == 1 ? true : false;` is identical to `return (num % 2) == 1;`

Comment: I wish to agree with you. However, I am confused because the online calculators I have tried are saying -17 % 2 = 1. This is where I am confounded,.

Comment: https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/modulo-of-negative-numbers/. In all case, use some Math.abs if you dont care about the sign

Comment: However? In other words you don't agree with me. Otherwise there is no However

Comment: Different languages use different conventions but most seem to return the sign of the dividend. Python always returns the positive remainder, which I prefer. You can  always get the positive remainder by `return ((num % 2) + 2) % 2 == 1 ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation I found on [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) concerning the mod operator in javascript is that the returned value takes the sign of the dividend (the number being divided: -17 in your case).

This is the same in mathematics when you are dividing -17/2. The answer is -8.5, and if you only want the whole number, then you will get -8 - 1/2. Meaning that -1 is the remaining of your division.

You will find the same answer in C and Go Programming languages.

I do not know why Python does return 1 in such a case. My opinion is python only returns the integer value and ignores the sign.

It is safe to say a number is odd when the remainder is different from 0.